Why does my blender use normal map to render strange shadows in cycles, but everything is normal in eevee?
Why does my blender use normal map to render strange shadows in cycles, but everything is normal in eevee?
And it is normal in marmoset tool or maya, which means that it is not a normal map or a problem with the model.


